# Pure functions and the outer scope

Tags: functional-programming, scope, pure-function

Excuse my ignorance, I come from the C family of languages but zero exposure to functional languages. I've read that pure functions only generate output based on a given input. Same input gives the same output regardless of other conditions. But something bothers me.

A simple case would be `array.filter` which takes in an array and a function to determine what gets included and what does not.

```
const newArray = oldArray.filter(item => condition);

// or put verbosely

import somethingFromTheOutside from './a-module';

const newArray = oldArray.filter(filterFunction);

function filterFunction(item, index, arr){
  return item.value = somethingFromTheOutside;
}
```

The callback only receives the current array item, the item index, and the array itself. Now if the callback were to remain pure, then `condition` should not reach out to the outer scope and only operate on the 3 pieces of information that was given to it. But how would `array.filter` be possible if its callback is not allowed to reach out to data outside the function?

What patterns are there so that the above can be achieved using pure functions? Also, if pure functions are not allowed to reach out to the surrounding scope, doesn't that make the entire resolution mechanism pointless if we're dealing with pure functions? Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Accessing outside state from within a function (doing this is usually called a closure) does not necessarily imply that the closure is impure.  See @RobertHarvey's answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/235176/63202

Answer (score 0):

Here's the terse answer.

When the expression `item => condition` is evaluated, the value of `condition` becomes a part of the function that results. Different values of `condition` will give you different functions. This is how the function can use the value of `condition` while remaining pure.